# Okular Document Review annotation bar

Tags: 20.10, okular

[image]I am using the latest Okular (version 20.04.0 Snaped). Since I use Annotations/typewriter most often — it is impossible to place the annotation bar onto the toolbar — visible & easy to access.
The only option available is through tools/review only when a document is open.

Any idea how can it be done?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Can you edit your question and provide a screenshot to indicate what you want? Okular's review annotation bar can be shown/hidden with the keyboard shortcut F6 or F7 (I don't remember which one)

Comment: Sorry for not being lucid. Here is the screenshot for which you asked. My objective is to fix the annotation bar on the toolbar next to the other tool bar on a permanent basis for ease of access to "typewrite" .

Comment: I can't see any screenshot. You can edit your question to add a link to the screenshot

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see a provision to upload the screenshot for you to see it. Anyway, if you go to tools/Review you will see the Annotation bar floats — either on the left vertically or on top horizontally below the toolbar. I want to place it on the toolbar on permanent bases for ease of access.

Comment: Again sorry. I did post the screenshot on the original post.